# Why is the Haddock documentation not showing up on Hackage?

Tags: haskell, cabal, hackage, haddock, leksah

I've got a [package on Hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hspec) that has haddock generated documentation but it isn't showing up on the Hackage page. I'm able to upload everything successfully but the documentation doesn't show up.

I generate the documentation with `cabal haddock` or with `Package > Build Documentation` in the Leksah IDE.

When I go to `Package > Open Doc` in Leksah, it can't find it because it's looking for `dist/doc/html/hspec/hspec/index.html` but the generated file is at `dist/doc/html/hspec/index.html`. I assume that Hackage is also looking in the same place.

I'm guessing that my source files aren't in the expected places, but I don't know how else they should be.

The source and directory structure can be found at https://github.com/trystan/hspec.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Packages are only built/documentation generated on a periodic basis. I don't know how often it is now -- used to be daily, but I think is somewhat more frequent. In any case, you should wait. Eventually, it will either build and generate documentation, or the build log will show what error took place.

Comment: It was every 6 hours last time I investigated.

Comment: It's been there for a couple weeks now, still no documentation.

Comment: It might be worth investigating these build errors: http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/hspec/0.2.0/logs/failure/ghc-7.0